# Excel VBA - Error using Range.Find method

Tags: excel, vba

I are building a program in VBA that will basically, paste text into a spreadsheet using the excel for VBA. The following error has stated to happen:

```
error on the xlvalues on this line: FoundCell = oSheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:=currentDay, LookIn:=xlvalues)

error is xlValues is not declared or may not be accessible due to its protection level
```

Code:

```
' Find Current Day In Excel Sheet
 Dim currentDay As String = String.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) ' Todays Date In Format To Search Spreadsheet
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range

FoundCell = oSheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:=currentDay, LookIn:=xlvalues)

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
MsgBox(currentDay & " Found In Row: " & FoundCell.Row)
Else
MsgBox(currentDay & " Not Found In Sheet " & oSheet.Name)
End If
```

Any help would be much appricated,

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: As far as I am aware isshould be in with the excel import, what should it be delcared as?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is possibly misleading because you parameters look ok. The `Range.Find` method returns a range object, so in VBA you must use the `Set` keyword:

```
Set FoundCell = oSheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:=currentDay, LookIn:=xlvalues)
```

You might struggle with finding dates because Excel stores them as a number and then displays them as a date. Depending on your data you might need to search for the formatted text or using a `Date` variable.

If you are writing this in VBA, this line will not work:

```
Dim currentDay As String = String.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

You must declare variables separately from initialising them.

```
Dim currentDay As String
currentDay = Format(Date(),"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to ChipsLetten (but a little slower!), I altered your code as below.

```
Sub notableopenfile()

    ' Find Current Day In Excel Sheet
    Dim currentDay As String
    'currentDay = Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) ' Todays Date In Format To Search Spreadsheet
    currentDay = Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    Dim FoundCell As Range

    Set FoundCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:=currentDay, LookIn:=xlValues) 'need 'set' here

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (currentDay & " Found In Row: " & FoundCell.Row)
    Else
        MsgBox (currentDay & " Not Found In Sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name)
    End If

End Sub
```